# Add source files to my jar using Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I wanted to know the right way I should act.
I have a project which I have compiled into a jar file using maven plugins.

Now, I need to add javadoc , source code , of my project and my tests.

How should I do it?

Basically maven have plugin to deal with such cases.
If I use those plugins I end up with : 
`project.jar`
`project-sources.jar`
`project-javadoc.jar`
`project-tests.jar`

Is this the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you're describing is generally considered the correct way to build javadoc, source, and test jars with maven.

Answer (score 1):

The [Maven cookbook](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) describes how to attach source and javadoc arifects